# How to merge objects with background in Illustrator and export them as PNG

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I am new to Illustrator and learning it for my graphic needs. I am working to create buttons for an app so I grabbed some free resources from the internet. I found and eps file for different states of button and I want to extract buttons from that and export them to png (with transparent background for the round corners) but I cannot figure it out how to do that.
Here is the preview of the eps file with 3 buttons
[image]

But the problem is that background too contributes to the object effects and if I remove background this happens.

[image]

So what I need is to:

1. merge the background so that objects have that background effects.
2. copy the object (one button with background) to photoshop.
3. export it then from photoshop.

I can copy and export from photoshop but how to merge the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the EPS, unfortunately it's not as simple as deleteing the background, there are a lot of overlapping gradients with blending modes and what-not.

1. Mask off the background. I just drew rectangles over each button, but you can copy & paste the existing shapes for a more acurate mask.

   Create a compound path out of your masking shapes (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>), select that and the background and create a clipping mask (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>).

[image]

2. Set the black stop on the gradients to transparent. Most of the gradients are the same so you can select one and do "*Select → Same → Fill Color*" to get most of them.

   There are a few white gradients too that aren't easy to spot on a white background, set those to be transparent too (Turn on the transparency grid to help you see them).

[image]

Ta-da:

[image]

Of course, if you're not too worried about the glow on the outside you could have just masked the whole thing to begin with instead of messing about with those gradients...